# Можно ли использовать дочерние элементы в h1?

Tags: html, html5, seo

Можно ли использовать em, strong, span внутри h1,h2,h3, если страница должна быть SEO оптимизированной? Как вообще относится гугл к дочерним элементам внутри заголовков? Или это вообще не корректно? Прошу отвечать только если вы уверенны в верности ответа и имеете опыт с SEO.

Comment: С точки зрения W3C стандартов любой строчный элемент может быть помещен внутрь блочного, а заголовки - блочные элементы.
Так почему же то, что является стандартом должно отвергаться поисковиками?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, можно (вот пару полезностей можешь почитать):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895082/can-another-tag-be-inside-a-html-5-heading-i-e-h1-h2-h3-etc
2. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20639/having-strong-tag-inside-the-h2-is-advisable-or-not
3. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42249/strong-and-em-tags-inside-h1-and-h2-and-seo-on-database-driven-website

Answer (score 1):

Я согласен с **Frank Sinatra**. Нет никаких запретов на применение этих элементов. Вероятно strong будет излишен, т.к. элемент h уже имеет в себе функцию усиления текста strong. Эти элементы могут быть полезны для внедрения в них разметки структурированными данными. В любом случае вы можете проверять валидность кода на **[валидаторе W3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. Этот валидатор покажет вам все ошибки исходного кода.